# Why solving the cryto puzzle is key in blockchain

Tags: blockchain

Can somebody explain in detail as:

```
why solving a crypto puzzle by blockchain nodes is key in blockchain systems? 

What factor can make a node solve the puzzle earlier than others.

How is it important for security in blockchain system?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some good questions that address the fundamental nature of many contemporary blockchains.

The "puzzle" being solved is the random guessing of a number that creates a resulting hash in line with the blockchain's protocol. Digging deeper into this, hashing algorithms are a one-way function where the resulting hash is easy to achieve from the input but it is impossible other than guessing to achieve an input that would achieve a given hash. The Bitcoin blockchain's protocol for example at the time of writing this requires a valid resulting hash to contain 19 leading zeros. When a person is solving this puzzle, they are guessing an additional input (called the "nonce") that when combined with all the other information of the block (transactions, previous block reference, etc.) yields an output hash from the protocol's hashing algorithm that fits its requirements. By completing this puzzle we are able to finalize the block and add it to the blockchain. We use the information in the blocks to maintain the ledger of ownership on the network.

The determinant of solving speed, in the long run/on average, is the amount of guesses a network participant is able to put forth in a given amount of time. This is primarily determined by one's hardware, which has given rise to the current frenzied state of the mining equipment market. If I am able to do 10 guesses per second and you can only do 1 guess per second, I will usually be the first one between the two of us to find a nonce that fits the protocol's requirements. Of course sometimes you will get lucky with your guess and beat me, but on average I will be first more often. One slight aside here is that this question is particularly relevant to consensus mechanisms like proof of work (Bitcoin and Ethereum currently both use this) where many miners are competing against each other to find the nonce first and are rewarded for winning this race. However in some other consensus mechanisms like proof of stake, it is less of a race and more of it being one's turn to solve for a nonce which will be verified by other network participants. Here there isn't a race between network participants so the need to have very powerful hardware is greatly diminished.

The solving of the puzzle brings together the block in question (as discussed in answer to question 1). Blocks in the blockchain feature a reference to the previous block and are therefore "chained" together. This solving of the puzzle is important for security as once the puzzle is solved we have a nonce that we can join with the block data to determine the state of the block at any point after by checking to see if the resulting hash is in line with the protocol's requirements. Recall from earlier that hash functions are one-way functions. The person solving for the nonce did the hard work by randomly guessing values for the nonce to achieve a valid hash. We can now plug the nonce and block contents into the hashing algorithm and easily achieve a resulting hash. This is important and helps to provide security to the blockchain as we will now know if anyone goes back to change the data of a previous block. This leads us to the idea that blockchains are "immutable." If someone were to go back in time to change the data of a block we would not only be able to see that the solved nonce along with the changed block contents do not yield the same hash but it will also be reflected in all sequential blocks from the one that was changed because the reference to the previous block that is included in the block's data will be different so the resulting hash of all of these blocks will be different too.

I hope these responses are of help to you!